# Shrinking a layout in android - Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an android launcher. I'm using `RecyclerView` with `FlexboxLayoutManager`. I want to shrink (zoom-out) my layout while I'm dragging `RecyclerView` items. I have implemented `onDragListener` but don't know how to shrink Grid.

Comment: What does "shrink" mean?

Comment: you can use ViewCompat.animate(recyclerview).scaleX(0.8).scaleY(0.8).start();

Comment: @M. Prokhorov - Shrink like zooming out of homepage when long-clicking or draging icons.

Comment: @Omkar T - Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.